# Static PHP profiler for scripts that are not running off a webserver?

Tags: php, scripting, profiler

So I've been trying to debug some code written by someone else but it's messy because I have to trace through several files and arrays just to get one thing out of it.

Are there any profiling tools for PHP scripts which are just run through the CLI? i.e. not running for a webserver?

I've looked at alot of the other suggestions (XDebug, XH, PHP_debug etc) but they all seem to be specific to PHP code running on servers.

What I want is something that can run through a PHP script/directory, and model it so I can read through variables, arrays and functions.

Your help would be much appreciated,

Comment: XDebug is not only for webservers, I have no problems profiling / tracing / stepping through command line code with it, using either KDevelop or vim. What makes you think you need a webserver for this?

Comment: Thanks Wrikken, My bad, I guess I wasn't very clear about what I wanted/needed. The problem is that I'm new to php and trying to understand some fairly complex code on a live environment, I can't really run and step through scripts as they interface with many different devices and databases.. I guess I was hoping for a profiler that could be done without invoking the code.. probably asking for too much. :)

Comment: I am indeed not aware of any profiler that runs without actually running the code. You can get some automatic documentation from phpDocumentor, but that's just lists of classes / functions / constants, not actual flow of code. Then again, with a bit of effort you should hopefully be able to setup a test environment in which you can run everything without touching live data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get this http://jenkins-php.org/ running or you simply use your IDE (NetBeans or Eclipse) + remote debugging. If you only need something quick with CLI use http://phpmd.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Our [PHP Profiler](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Profilers/PHPProfiler.html) doesn't care how your PHP pages are invoked, so yes, you can run them from the CLI and get profiling data.   There's a corresponding test coverage tool.